# Does simple past always indicate an event that happened at a 'specific time' in the past?

Tags: simple-past

From what I understand, the verb tense 'simple past' is used for an event that happened at a specific time in the past.

The sentence 'Sam played tennis yesterday.' is simple past because it happened at a specific time in the past (yesterday).

However, if I change the sentence to:

> 'Sam played tennis.'

What will be the verb tense in this case? This event did not happen at a specific time in the past. Will it still be simple past or will it be something else?

Also if I change the sentence even more to:

> 'Sam used to play tennis.'

What will be the verb tense now? It feels like simple past to me, but is it?

Comment: What makes you think  "used to" is in the different tense from "played"?

Comment: @Rathony I don't know. Just asking. I feel like I still don't have a good enough grasp of how tenses work.

Comment: Simple past can be imperfect/habitual or perfect/one off, depending on context (he played yesterday, perfect, he played as a kid, imperfect, he played, ambiguous). *Used to + verb* will only be interpreted as imperfect/past habitual.

Comment: @guifa what is the distinction between perfect and imperfect? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first two statements are equivalent:

> Sam played tennis yesterday. 
>   Sam played tennis.

Simple past is used to show that the subject has completed an action. A specific time frame for the event is intended when using simple past tense. However, the speaker can choose to include or omit the actual time of the event.

The next statement is:

> Sam used to play tennis.

'Used to' is an imperfect form of verb that combines the past tense and the present tense. It is used to imply a habitual action: one that has repeatedly occurred in the past. In the above statement, 'used to' means that Sam had a habit of playing tennis at some point in the past. Sam does not have this habit anymore.

You can find more information about 'Used to' on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_markers_of_habitual_aspect#Used_to). A tutorial on this usage can be found [here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/usedto.html).

Comment: "combines the past tense and the present tense" huh?

Comment: @guifa : I'll try to explain that statement in another way. Let's assume that I have a habit: I play video games (simple present tense). Now, let's shift the time frame a bit. I had this habit in the past, but I don't anymore. 'Used to' is the construct needed to express such a situation. 'I used to play video games' implies that I had a habit of playing video games. I do not have this habit anymore. To re-iterate, the action happened in the past, but it was a a habit (which is represented using simple present tense). Does that clear up the confusion?